# How to fetch each role execution result in a loop in a playbook

Tags: loops, ansible

I need to run a playbook role by calling it via include_role for multiple servers with a "loop" syntax. I'm trying to write a code which gather each role execution result in the loop but not yet been able to reach the solution.

That is, I need to implement a playbook which includes a code like below but this doesn't work for my purpose:

```yaml
- name: Calling a setup server role for each server
  include_role:
    name: "ansible_role_setup_server"
  vars:
    host_name: "{{ item.host_name }}"
  loop: "{{ server_list }}"
  register: execution_result
```

We give a server list which has target server host names and for each server we need to run "ansible_role_setup_server" role.

We need to gather the role execution result information, especially its execution result which is set as a variable(success_or_failure) on the role side for each server respectively. And I'd like each result to be put into a list variable finally with corresponding host name.

But I've not yet been able to find the way.

I tried to use `register` but it didn't work as it only gathered "Calling a setup server role for each server" task information itself.

Comment: Hi and welcome here. You seem to be right in the middle of an [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info). You would certainly benefit from giving a bit more background on what you are exactly trying to do. Moreover your question does not meet the awaited quality standard to actually be answerable. I suggest you read [ask] paying attention to the [mre] section, and then [edit] your question to enhance its content. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Actually I believe what I've been getting stuck on is related to the second issue of "Allow to register a result (aggregate of all tasks + top level that reflects above)" in the link below: 
https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/136

As far as I check, there's no way to extract a role execution result directly from each loop when include_role is used, due to lack of ansible functionality as written in the issue link above. My skill may not be enough to judge it at all, though.

I almost gave up and now looking for another way to accomplish my purpose.